# Reusing property editors for Blend 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, expression-blend

I have a custom silverlight control, which exposes a property with DataGridLength type. Now I want  that property to have the same editor as a common DataGridColumn's Width property, with the combobox and everything, like this:
 [image]
instead, I only get a simple TextBox, with "Auto" written in, with no way to set to SizeToCells and so on.
I assume I need a DesignTime attribute, but none of the ones I found in ComponentModel namespace even came close...

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just have to create an Enum with the all the values autorized (Pixels, SizeToCells, etc ...), you that Enum as the type of your property DataGridLength and then, in the code of your control, take the corresponding action regarding the value sent.

Comment: but Pixels and Star also take on a value. so then I'd have to take an enum AND an double which is EXACTLY what DataGridLength struct does. So no, this road doesnt leads to greatness. I want to reuse the same typeeditor not hack around with property type.